# Efficient use of a fifo for an audio streaming application

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, signal-processing, fifo

I have an audio dsp application which produces output at a significantly faster rate than real-time, using a pool of threads. This is intended for use in games, and the audio must be streamed with a fairly low latency. Each finished buffer ends up in the main mixer thread, from which I need to deliver it to the application programmer. I figured I might have a read_samples method in the main class which takes a buffer pointer and a number of samples to read, and returns the number of samples actually read.

I am looking into a lock free fifo, namely the single producer/single consumer queue from boost.lockfree. My current design goals are as follows:

1. It is important that data is pushed in and out from the fifo very 
   quickly, so we want as few blocking operations as possible. Most of the time the application programmers will probably be invoking the read_samples method of the main class inside an interrupt level priority thread, as a lot of audio I/O subsystems receive data that way (e.g. through a callback). Therefore, we come to points 2 and 3.
2. If read_samples is invoked and there aren't enough samples in the fifo to 
   deliver the requested amount, we should probably take what we have (if 
   anything) and then return immediately without blocking. If we lock and wait, 
   we could affect a lot of other audio playback that the interrupt level 
   thread callback may be responsible for.
3. If the producer tries to write to a full buffer, we want to wait until 
   all samples have been written. We want to let the user read while we're 
   waiting to write though, so that they can clear up space in the buffer for 
   us. It is no problem for the producer to wait, so that part does not need to be lock free. By setting a size for the ring buffer that roughly corresponds to our latency expectations, we can make sure that the producer gives us just 
   enough data to avoid playback stalling but no more than that.

Points one and two are trivial to actually implement, provided that my design decisions in terms of when and when not to block seem reasonable. It is the third point that gives me a bit of trouble. Is there an efficient way to 
lock until the buffer is no longer full, and wake up only when we can write 
more? I can easily detect what the size of the buffer is, and this is an atomic operation thankfully. But how to lock and unlock appropriately puzzles me, especially because we do want to be able to interrupt the lock 
prematurely if it is time to shut down for instance. What do I use for this? A condition variable? If so, I would be really greatful if anyone could offer some pseudocode. I understand how to use barriers, but haven't looked into 
condition variables too much yet and am not sure I understand them. Especially since 
they can apparently wake up without the condition having been fulfilled, which seems strange. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does there have to be actual data in the FIFO?  In high-performance I/O, it's more common to make a queue of pointers to 'empty' buffers available to the driver. The driver fills a buffer, (or partial buffer and length), with data, queues off the buffer pointer to the higher level and immediately dequeues another buffer pointer for the next lot of data to come in.  The driver signals a semaphore every time it queues a  buffer back so that the higher-level thread knows there is one to dequeue and process.

Comment: 'It is important that data is pushed in and out from the fifo very quickly' - it's trivial to design/use queue that requires no hard locking at all, as long as there's only one producer, one consumer and you're only queueing pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Martin. Pushing pointers to buffers in the fifo is a good idea that I'll have to look into. I did solve my original problem using a condition variable (I finally figured out how to use them properly). So now the producer waits patiently for the consumer, as I intended.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get the blocking behavior when the producer has produced too much material is with a condition variable. The producer calls wait when it has reached its limit, and the consumer then calls notify_all as soon as it has consumed some data. The producer then wakes up and generates more, etc.